# MATLAB: Matrix Image Scaling Error

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

I have a problems with dimensions of the picture.  It is very important because it represents a velocity structure, and so the picture I got is somehow deformed.

```
figure
load('newvel.dat')
v=reshape(newvel,106,14)
vt=transpose(v)
imagesc(vt) ;
```

I would like my picture to have ratio 106/14:7.57:1.  Should I setup the axes or what?  Is it possible and how?

Comment: what software do you use???

Comment: The syntax is MATLAB.  The author didn't originally place this in the tag and the title.  I've suggested an edit.